# How to capture file opened in browser and post it to backend using java script

Tags: javascript

I am writing chrome extension to capture file opened in chrome browser like if i selected a pdf it opens in browser and i want to save the file in my datastore using a webservice my code looks like this.How can i capture the current  pdf or image file and post to my  webservice?

popup.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body { 
                min-width: 420px; 
                overflow-x: hidden; 
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
                font-size: 12px; 
            }
            input, textarea { 
                width: 420px; 
            }
            input#save { 
                font-weight: bold; width: auto; 
            }
        </style>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="addbookmark">
            <p><label for="username">UserName</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p><label for="password">Password</label><br />
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="50" value="" /></p>

            <p>
                <input id="save" type="submit" value="Save to Store" />
                <span id="status-display"></span>
            </p>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.js

```
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Bookmark Extension Example",
    "description": "POST details of the current page to a remote endpoint.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/", 
        "https://*/"
    ]
}
```

popup.js

```
// Global reference to the status display SPAN
var statusDisplay = null;

// POST the data to the server using XMLHttpRequest
function addBookmark() {

    // Cancel the form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // The URL to POST our data to
    var postUrl = 'http://mydrive.com';

    // Set up an asynchronous AJAX POST request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', postUrl, false);

    // Prepare the data to be POSTed


    // Set correct header for form data 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // Handle request state change events
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 

        // If the request completed
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

            statusDisplay.innerHTML = '';
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                // If it was a success, close the popup after a short delay
                statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Saved!';
                window.setTimeout(window.close, 1000);
            } else {// Show what went wrong
                statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Error saving: ' + xhr.statusText;
            }
        }
    };

    // Send the request and set status
    xhr.send(null);
    statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Saving...';
}

// When the popup HTML has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
    // Handle the bookmark form submit event with our addBookmark function
    document.getElementById('addbookmark').addEventListener('submit', addBookmark);
    // Cache a reference to the status display SPAN
    statusDisplay = document.getElementById('status-display');
    // Call the getPageInfo function in the background page, injecting content_script.js 
    // into the current HTML page and passing in our onPageInfo function as the callback
  //  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().getPageInfo(onPageInfo);
});
```

Comment: file upload can be done on form submit not via ajax..
or use Form data object to upload via ajax..
but form data isn't supported in older versions of I.E
here's the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: for now i am trying in chrome

Comment: @Shashank: you can certainly upload files with ajax, xhr.send(inpFiles.files[0]) works. it's a matter of making them look like traditional uploads that FormData tidies up for you.

Comment: lets assume i have opened file from gmail in preview mode or opened a pdf in browser how to capture it?

Comment: @dandavis well i never used xhr.send for file uploads so i don kno anyway thanks will give it a try...